# Why does SSH not consult /etc/hosts?

Tags: ssh, hosts

I'm administrating a networked environment where the users authenticate over NIS.
All machines can be used to SSH into the server but one.
On the machine in question, I get the message

`ssh: connect to host servername port 22: Connection refused`

I compared `strace` outputs from the machine in question and a machine that can SSH into the server correctly.
It turns out the machine that can't SSH into the server doesn't consult `/etc/hosts` while the machine that can SSH correctly does. Both machines have `/etc/hosts` set up with the server's name and IP. In the end, the machine that doesn't consult `/etc/hosts` ends up trying to connect to  `127.0.0.1` (localhost) and fails with the above message. What can be causing this?

Additional information:

- The server I'm trying to SSH into also acts as the name server and both machines consult it while trying to SSH into it.
- The machine that can't SSH into the server can SSH correctly into other machines when I do

  `ssh machinename`

  The `strace` logs show that the machine consults the nameserver (this time successfully) and manages to resolve the remote machine name correctly and connect to it.

EDIT: I will gladly provide any additional information that you think might help solve this issue.

Comment: What do you get when you add -vvv to the ssh command?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It sounds to me like the problem host does not have a correctly configured `nsswitch.conf`.

The `hosts` line of `/etc/nsswitch.conf` should look something like this:

```
hosts:  files nisplus nis dns
```

However, the exact contents will vary due to your environment. You should compare against working hosts and make changes accordingly.

Comment: Right on the money! I compared against a working host and made the required changes and that did it. 
Thanks a lot!
I'd vote you up if I had the rep :)

Comment: @JosephR. You sure have the rep now! :-)