# SSH not working from one specific computer

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I can connect from every other computer on the LAN, as well as externally. It connects fine to other machines running SSHD. When trying ssh with verbosity, I get the following readout:

```
$ ssh -vvv 192.168.1.9
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.9 [192.168.1.9] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/Steven/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Steven/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/Steven/.ssh/id_dsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/Steven/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /home/Steven/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Steven/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Steven/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Any idea what I might have messed up? I don't recall changing in the SSH config files, only adding some users to groups to experiment with permissions. Even when I try not specifying an account (as above) it still hangs at "Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2" for a minute before giving the final error. I'm running Ubuntu Server 12.04 x86, for what it's worth.

Comment: Have you tried specifying `/dev/null` as the identity file?

Comment: have you checked ssh related logs in remote server i.e 192.168.1.9 ?

Comment: Looks like a network problem. You could run `tcpdump -i eth0 -n host 192.168.1.9 and tcp port 22`. You also may try ssh-agent and `ssh-add /home/Steven/.ssh/id_dsa`

Comment: Take a look at some of the solutions in this SU Q&A: http://superuser.com/questions/568891/ssh-works-in-putty-but-not-terminal

Comment: What are the changes you made, before this issue ?

Comment: please give us some more information on your server and the network. how many interfaces are on the client/server-side? are both in the same network? i guess question and answer go through different interfaces on the server.

Comment: Can you also add Output of `telnet server_ip 22`

Comment: Try shutting down iptables and ip6tables services (if they exist). SELinux can cause some trouble like this as well.

Comment: @user42648 Which OS is running on your client machine?

Comment: Could be a badly configured `nsswitch.conf`. Take a look at [this question I asked earlier](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55014/why-does-ssh-not-consult-etc-hosts)

Comment: Is the machine claiming to use ssh agent and the agent is broken?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What this means, ultimately, is that the SSH server on the other end has crashed or is in some way not working. It's still listening on the socket but it's not capable of performing a cryptographic handshake.

The only solution is to restart the process on the remote side.

Answer (score 2):

I had this very same problem, what i found was my IP keept getting added to the 
etc/hosts.deny  file.

I resolved this by simply logging into another VPS server then connecting ssh into the blocked VPS  and removed my (home static) IP from the hosts.deny file.

Answer (score 1):

My First attempt was to find "`ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`", and cross check with source code , but unfortunately I haven't found any. So with several method I tried to replicate same problem in my side , but unable to create same issue in my side, as you can see as below.

**With sshd_config DenyUsers root**

Client Side log

> Permission denied, please try again

Server Side log

> Jul  2 02:47:32 server sshd[27118]: User root from CLIENT_IP not
>   allowed because listed in DenyUsers

**With hosts.deny**

sshd : CLIENT_IP

Client side debug log:

> ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Server Side log

> Jul  2 02:46:28 server sshd[27100]: refused connect from CLIENT_IP
>   (CLIENT_IP)

**With PAM deny**

Client Side log:

> Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).

Server Side log:

> PAM-listfile: Refused user xyz for service ssh

**With Lock Account**

Client Side log:

> debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply debug1:
>   Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
>   Permission denied, please try again.

Server Side log:

> Jul  2 02:57:16 server sshd[27303]: pam_unix(sshd:auth):
>   authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser=
>   rhost=CLIENT_IP  user=usertest Jul  2 02:57:17 server sshd[27303]:
>   Failed password for usertest from CLIENT_IP port 39431 ssh2 Jul  2
>   02:57:35 server sshd[27303]: Failed password for usertest from
>   CLIENT_IP port 39431 ssh2

**Then after doing some Google search, it's seems this issue because :**

- Duplicate IP in Your Network
- Might be it's bug.

Comment: The "Connection reset by peer" is a generic socket error message; you would not find it in the SSH sources. Look for a network read in `ssh_exchange_identification`. Anyway, this looks more like a firewall issue or similar.

Answer (score -1):

This can happen if the routing between the two computers is different. It is worthwhile to look into both the routing configurations of the two endpoints as well as any firewalls that the packets pass through.

Comment: How, exactly, does the path that a packet takes affect whether or not the handshake succeeds???

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error. I have fixed it by doing

`chmod 600 my-key.pem`

Comment: Can you explain how this is relevant to the question at hand?

Answer (score -2):

Try: `ssh -2 name@ip` or `ssh -2 -l name ip`

Comment: Do you want to explain how you think this is relevant?